# How to create converter in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, converters

I'm working in a project with [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) JavaScript library. I have one view model called BaseViewModel with one observable property called isAuthenticated.

The isAuthenticated property is filled with a boolean type with true for authenticated peoples and false for not authenticated peoples. Below one simple example:

```
var BasicViewModel = {
   this.isAuthenticated = ko.observable();
}
```

Inside my project this property is bound on a span element like the code below:

```
<span id="parking" data-bind="text: BasicViewModel.isAuthenticated"></span>
```

Now, I would show inside my span element one text like:

- Authenticated
- Not Authenticated

I know that I can create one computed property but is there nothing like WPF Converter for perform this action? For example:

```
<span id="parking" data-bind="text: BasicViewModel.isAuthenticated, Converter=myConverter"></span>
```

Comment: Solution that is more generic than computed variable would be a custom binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest approach to this is just to write a converter function and call it in the binding.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.isAuthenticated = ko.observable(false);
  self.myConverter = function(bool) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(bool);
    return value ? 'Authenticated' : 'Not Authenticated';
  };

  setTimeout(function() {
    self.isAuthenticated(true)
  }, 1500);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span id="parking" data-bind="text: myConverter(isAuthenticated)"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a normal read-only computed that reads from `isAuthenticated` and returns the text to display.  Anything else seems like needless over-complication.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.isAuthenticated = ko.observable(false);
  self.isAuthenticatedText = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.isAuthenticated() ? "Authenticated" : "Not Authenticated"
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    self.isAuthenticated(true);
  }, 1500);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<span id="parking" data-bind="text: isAuthenticatedText"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight-up analogous solution to a converter. There *are* multiple ways to do something similar.

**Custom Binding Handler**

The closest to how a converter works would be to create a custom binding. With WPF you'd have both a converter and a value binding, in a custom binding handler you do both at once.

The default `text` binding could be considered a binding for text values that renders them as, well, plain text. You can re-use its logic and create a binding handler that renders boolean observables differently:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textBool = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var field = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        field = !!field ? "So True!" : "False!";
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { return field; });
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
<span data-bind="textBool: BasicViewModel.isAutenticated"></span>
```

**Writeable Computed Observable**

You could create a writeable computed that does this. If you create one straight up you'd get this:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  var _isAuthenticated = ko.observable(false);
  self.isAuthenticated = ko.computed({
    read: function() { return _isAuthenticated() ? "True!" : "False..."; },
    write: function(val) { _isAuthenticated(val); }
  );
}
```

You could even factor that out to a utility function to be used instead of `ko.computed`, e.g.:

```
function createBoolComputed(trueText, falseText) {
  var _isAuthenticated = ko.observable(false);
  trueText = trueText || "True!";
  falseText = falseText || "False!";

  return ko.computed({
    read: function() { return _isAuthenticated() ? "True!" : "False..."; },
    write: function(val) { _isAuthenticated(val); }
  );
}
```

And use it like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.isAuthenticated = createBoolComputed(/* parameters optional */);
}
```

**Custom Template**

If you stray from the analogy of a WPF converter even further, you could also use a template for this purpose. That would be especially useful if you want to render special DOM for different values.